# Fan fiction where Snape adopts Harry Potter

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape

I don’t remember too much about this fan fiction. I do remember that Harry is still in Gryffindor and that Snape still doesn’t like Harry. They’re not father and son, but I do remember that it had tags where Snape adopts Harry. They don’t get along at first because Dumbledore took Harry to Snape to take care of him for the rest of the summer, I think, but they ended up getting along for the most part.

One part I do remember quite clearly is that Harry got kidnapped by Voldemort and when everyone was freaking out, Snape got called in and Snape was trying to think of a way to get both of them to safety. He arrived but couldn’t get them out yet, as Voldemort was suspicious about Snape and told him to take out Harry’s eyes for him. Harry trusted him before that and so Snape did it to buy them some time before they could leave. As soon as he (Snape) was able to, he threw a curse at someone and Apparated them out.

Later that night, Harry woke up from a nightmare and was yelling for Snape. Everyone thought he was yelling due to what happened and was feeling sorry, but it was actually Harry not feeling safe and wanting Snape at his side. Snape arrives and is able to calm him down, and as he’s leaving he yells at Poppy to get him immediately the next time Harry’s yelling for him.

Comment: Preliminary research can be done here : https://www.fanfiction.net/search/?keywords=adopt+snape&type=story&match=any&formatid=any&sort=0&genreid1=0&genreid2=0&characterid1=0&characterid2=0&characterid3=0&characterid4=0&words=0&ready=1&categoryid=224. You can tweek it more if you remember the size, or the quality

Comment: @Kit_rosy29 This might be a hard question to answer. There have been many fanfictions written on that subject, and since none of them are official, it is hard to know which one you are looking for.

Comment: Do you remember what site you read this on? and roughly how many years ago you may have read it?

Answer (score 2):

[A Year Like None Other](https://archiveofourown.org/works/742072/chapters/1382061) by aspeninthesunlight.

Harry yells for Snape in [Chapter 29](https://archiveofourown.org/works/742072/chapters/1382050):

> The windows in the hospital wing shattered into millions of tiny shards as the stone walls abruptly buckled, then righted themselves.
>
> And still Harry screamed, even as he felt another enormous surge of magic washing in him and over him and out through his skin. The walls all around began to blaze with such fierce, unnatural light that Harry could feel it even if he couldn't see it.
>
> The world began collapsing all around him; only his screams were real. Beyond desperate, they were begging, pleading, *frantic*, and this time, there was more than a name to them. *Snape. Now. Now. Now. Snape. Now!*

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in some extra info into your answer perhaps? Why do you think this is what the OP is looking for? What details from the question match the fan-fic you've linked?

Comment: @Deepa - Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this answer. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this answer by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this answer without approval from other users, and leave comments (like this one) directly beneath it.